# How to add an image to text that will show up randomly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[What it looks like in unity. I have also drawn a red arrow to show what I am trying to move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TpXJ.png)

I am trying to make a quiz game that would show a random word with a corresponding image. I am able to show a random question and a random image at the same time. My problem is that the image that will show up will not always be the correct image for the word. Is it possible to move the random image up and place it with the random text?

I have tried attaching the image directly with the text and the problem is that the text will disappear and only the image will stay. What I did to get the image into the game object was by repeating everything for the text.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Question[] questions;
    public Image[] images;

    private static List<Question> unansweredQuestions;
    private static List<Image> unansweredImages;

    private Question currentQuestion;
    private Image currentImage;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text factText;
    [SerializeField]
    private Image factImage;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text trueAnswerText;
    [SerializeField]
    private Image trueAnswerImage;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text falseAnswerText;
    [SerializeField]
    private Image falseAnswerImage;

    [SerializeField]
    private Animator animator;

    [SerializeField]
    private float timeBetweenQuestions = 1f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float timeBetweenImages = 1f;

    void Start()
    {
        if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
        {
            unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
        }

        if (unansweredImages == null || unansweredImages.Count == 0)
        {
            unansweredImages = images.ToList<Image>();
        }

        SetCurrentQuestion();
    }

    void SetCurrentQuestion()
    {
        int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
        currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[randomQuestionIndex];

        int randomImageIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
        currentImage = unansweredImages[randomImageIndex];

        factText.text = currentQuestion.fact;

        if (currentQuestion.isTrue)
        {
            trueAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";
            falseAnswerText.text = "WRONG";
        }
        else
        {
            trueAnswerText.text = "WRONG";
            falseAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";
        }

    }

    IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion()
    {
        unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenQuestions);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

        unansweredImages.Remove(currentImage);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenQuestions);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
```

I expect the image and correct text to show up together randomly.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Its not clear from your post what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the small information I think you are trying to set a random question but with the correct image.

If this is the case:
The problem I see is you are using a list to access Question and Images. You can use Dictionaries to solve the issue.

```
public Question[] questions;
public Image[] images;
```

New:

```
Dictionary< int, Question> Questions;
Dictionary< int, Image> Images;
```

Integer here will be a random index that will be same for both dictionaries.

You can manually set the questions and images on runtime. then, whenever you want to assign an image to that random text, just get a random number using Random.Range function. it will return an integer that can be used as the index. Let me know if it helps.

PS: You can remove the space before int datatype.